# Obtain the largest positive eigenvalue (with its eigenvector)?

Tags: eigenvalues

`Eigenvalues[M,1]` can be used to return the largest eigenvalue in absolute value. Is there a simple way to obtain the largest positive eigenvalue instead, as well as the corresponding eigenvector/s?

Comment: `Eigensystem[M, 1]`?

Comment: @kglr That gives the largest eigenvalue according to *absolute* value. I want the largest *positive* eigenvalue (there might be another negative eigenvalue with larger absolute value that I do not want).

Comment: becko, i see. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
evv = Module[{es = Eigensystem[#], ord}, ord = Ordering[-es[[1]]]; es[[All, ord[[1]]]]] &;


m = N[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}];    
evv @ m
```

> {16.1168, {-0.231971, -0.525322, -0.818673}}

```
evv[-m]
```

> {1.11684, {0.78583, 0.0867513, -0.612328}}

**Update:** Using the options in Jens's answer in the q/a linked by @Carl

```
evv2 = Eigensystem[#, 1, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}][[All,1]]&;
evv2@ m
```

> {16.1168, {-0.231971, -0.525322, -0.818673}}

Comment: There is no way to bypass the computation of *all* the eigenvalues when you are only interested in the largest positive one?

Comment: @becko, good point. i can't think of any way.

Comment: I figured out something that could work in some cases, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Last@Sort@Cases[Transpose@Eigensystem@M,{_Real,__}]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to demonstrate the code by running in on `m` given in other answers.